# Change display refresh rate in Ubuntu 18.04 with cinnamon desktop

Tags: cinnamon

I have ubuntu 18.04 with cinnamon desktop, I am using several monitors. I can't find a way to change refresh rate and DPI settings per monitor. How to do this?